# How to make WebStorm stop complaining about node scripts?

Tags: javascript, webstorm, eslint, create-react-app

After `create-react-app` and `eject`, I got a file `scripts/build.js`. But WebStorm is complaining about that file:

[image]

How can I configure eslint config / WebStorm config correctly to avoid those error reporting?

Comment: include file in dependencies

Comment: @LeonelMatiasDomingos, what's the meaning of "include file in dependencies"?

Comment: I dont use webstorm. But you must include the file where process is defined as a librarie. That way you'll hace autocomplete also ...kind of

Comment: `Ctrl+click` on `process` - what declaration are you taken to?

Answer (score 0):

Go to File ->SETTINGS->Languages->javascript and include the file where you define process as a librarie